# VB.NET 2017 problems calling Power Shell command GET-WBSUMMARY

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I've successfully built a function in VB.NET which can call a PowerShell command, retrieve the results, and display the returned values in a DataGridView. It works - but for some reason it doesn't work with the particular PowerShell command I want to use!

If I pass the command "GET-PROCESS" with, for example, parameter "d*" I receive the results I would expect, if I pass the command "GET-WBSUMMARY" I get an error which says the command doesn't exist.

However if I open PowerShell and manually type GET-WBSUMMARY it works - I get the expected results.

The complication is that Get-WBSummary doesn't exist on my development computer, so I'm having to compile the application and install it on a server which does have the command to test.

Get-WBSummary returns a summary of the state of Windows Backup.

I'm not clear whether there is an issue with my code, whether it's a security issue, or something else completely.

Can anyone offer any suggestions with this?

Thanks,
David

```
Dim rSpace As Runspaces.Runspace = Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()
    rSpace.Open()

    Dim ps As PowerShell = PowerShell.Create
    ps.Runspace = rSpace

    Runspaces.Runspace.DefaultRunspace = rSpace

    ps.AddCommand("Get-WBSummary")

    Try
        Dim PSResults As List(Of PSObject) = ps.Invoke.ToList

        For Each OM As PSObject In PSResults

            Dim PSReport As New List(Of PSResultItem)

            For Each OMR As PSMemberInfo In OM.Members

                Try
                    PSReport.Add(New PSResultItem With {.ItemName = OMR.Name, .ItemValue = OMR.Value})
                Catch ex2 As Exception

                    PSReport.Add(New PSResultItem With {.ItemName = OMR.Name, .ItemValue = ex2.Message})

                End Try

            Next

            Dim frmResult As New Form2
            frmResult.DataGridView1.DataSource = PSReport.ToArray
            frmResult.Show()

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(String.Format("Could not execute command: {0}", ex.Message))
        Return

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

***Get-WBSummary*** is not a default Powershell cmdlet. 
The cmdlets for Windows Server Backup are contained in a Windows PowerShell snap-in. You must install the cmdlet snap-in.

But you have mentioned it is working, So I believe it is installed already.

Add the Windows Server Backup cmdlet snap-in to the instance of Windows PowerShell that you have opened by using the following command at the command prompt:

> add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup

By default, Windows PowerShell modules and snap-ins are not loaded in Windows PowerShell in Server 2k8 and R2 . From 2k13 it will be loaded by default.

After you add the snap-in part in your code , you can use your cmdlet ->> *Get-WBSummary*.

Hope you are clear with the approach now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your assistance, much appreciated. Not sure how I include the "add-pssnapin" line in my vb.net code however?

Comment: @David: just use like this:`"  add-pssnapin windows.serverbackup;  Get-WBSummary " `

Comment: Thanks for the pointer but I'm afraid that still doesn't seem to work.I tried adding "Add-PSSnapIn windows.serverbackup" as a command before my called to Get-WBSummary, then I get the exception `"System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException: No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4."`
Just to clarify that if I open a PowerShell via the START menu on the server, which is Server 2012R2, I can run get-wbsummary directly without having to add any cmblets first.

Comment: Can you look for this once: `get-pssnapin` and look for the windows.serverbackup.

Comment: So that means it is not present in the system. You need to install that and then you have to add the snap-in in the code.

Try running `Get-Command –Module WindowsServerBackup`. The Windows Server Backup cmdlets are built-in with PowerShell 4, so they no longer need to be installed, as they did in Server 2008 R2 and PowerShell verison 3.

If the backup feature is installed, you'll get a list of valid cmdlets you can run, and you're good to go. If not installed, you'll get nothing, and you need to install (or re-install) the feature.

Comment: could you reinstall the backup feature. It seems missing. Before that run `get-command - module WindowsServerBackup`

Comment: `Get-Command -Module WindowsServerBackup` works fine - it lists all the related commands, but that's in the PowerShell window. I'm not sure how this relates to me trying to make the same calls in VB code? The command has always worked at the command prompt, but not when called via code. If the WindowServerBackup commands are installed in PS4 by default should they not be automatically available when calling via code also?

Comment: Also just tried adding the line `rSpace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn("windowsserverbackup", PSException)` to my code - but that causes an exception.

Comment: no no . you do not need to add it externally. I think it is opening with 32 bit and defaults with version 2 not version 4 from the code. Could you please run $PSversiontable and see the version it returning from the code. Its getting hard to troubleshoot like this

Comment: Appreciate your continuing help with this - you've given me a few pointers which I will go and have a play around with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the PowerShell command I wanted is only available as a 64Bit command and therefore I had to recompile my application as 64Bit and then it works using exactly the original code I posted.